# Resolved ngResource promise contains no data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, ngresource

I have a Web Api controller which contains the following method:

```
[Route("CountThings/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CountThings(int id)
{
    //var numberOfThings = await _thingsRepository.CountThingsAsync(id);
    return Ok(123456);
}
```

As you can see, I'm always returning Ok with 123456 as data. This is for test purpose only.

In my Angular resource file I have this:

```
getCountThings: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: controllerPath + 'CountThings/:id',
    params: { id: '@id' }
}
```

And in my angular controller I have this:

```
thingsResource.getCountThings({ id: scope.id })
.$promise
.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    scope.numberOfThings = data;
 });
```

When I debug my application I can see that the API controller is called and returns correctly. In my angular controller I can see that the promise have been resolved when I log the data. But, I can't find a way to get to the data that should be returned (123456). If I log data.$resolved, this returns true.

How do I access the data that I want to use in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get primitives using angular `$resource`. Try returning json object from server (like `{ data: 123456 }`):

```
thingsResource.getCountThings({ id: scope.id })
.$promise
    .then(function (result) {
        scope.numberOfThings = result.data;
    });
```

See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4314) and explanation why resource has to be an object.

Alternative is to use `$http` service:

```
$http.get(controllerPath + 'CountThings/' + scope.id).then(function (result) {
    scope.numberOfThings = result.data;
});
```

In this case you don't need to modify anything on server.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that invoking a [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

Under the hood, AngularJS uses [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). All of the destination elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it. If the source is a primitive, nothing is copied. The resolved object or array will have no data.

You can't get primitives using AngularJS `$resource`.